# Keeping order for ggplot bar chart in R

Tags: r

I have the following ordered dataframe df:

```
                                  name freq
14                          John Smith   35
18                          Oliver White 23
15                     Wayland Johnson   12
19                          Joey Black    9
```

However when I plot in ggplot the order is not kept. Here is my ggplot code:

```
m <- ggplot(c_sorted, aes(x=name, y=freq))
m + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Would I have to order it again in the ggplot code?

With regards to a possible duplicate of:

[Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

How would I implement that solution for a dataframe? What would be the factor?

Comment: You need to order the name factor. Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: Would that solution still apply to a generic dataframe as opposed to table? If so, how?

Comment: Your `name` variable is the factor in this case. See this for more information: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/

Comment: vergatt, have a look at the bottom / last bit of code in Gavins answer at the link ... it explicitely shows how to do this

Comment: @user20650, I think I understand it... but am having trouble applying it to his earlier code: levels=names(sort(table(Position), 
                                                        decreasing=TRUE))))

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

I found a straightforward answer on this page:

[Plot data in descending order as appears in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961921/plot-data-in-descending-order-as-appears-in-data-frame)

Without using factors, you can just reorder within the ggplot code:

```
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(Category, -Count), y = Count)) +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```