# How can I descending reorder the dots in the scatter plot in ggplot based on the X values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am stuck at one trick in ggplot in R: I am trying to plot a scatter plot for metabolites (y axis) based on their VIP score (X axis)  here is the data [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQCaC.jpg), but when I run this in ggplot, it produced non-ordered scattering of the points as you can see here [Produced graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iXqc.jpg)
I would like to plot the same figure but with the dots being descending order from high to low similar to this one [wished Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYgWa.jpg)

I have tried using reorder but could not get my head around it.
Here is my script

```
ggplot(VIP, aes(x= `Mean decrease in model accuracy`, y = Metabolites, color = Class)) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

Highly appreciating for any help

Thanks

Comment: There are many similar questions on this forum, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961921/plot-data-in-descending-order-as-appears-in-data-frame/16968999#16968999. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but this example is different. Could you help in my example