# Sort geom_point in ascending order along one particular facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

Given the data below, I'm making a simple coefficient plot. I know I could supply a custom order and custom labels to manually rearrange 'var' using `scale_y_continuous()`, but surely there must be a way to reorder a continuous variable (coef, in my data) within ggplot?

Using the answer here ([Plot data in descending order as appears in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961921/plot-data-in-descending-order-as-appears-in-data-frame)), with `reorder()`, gives me the error "invalid argument to unary operator".

Adding to the complication is that I only want the y scale labels to appear once on the far left axis, which means I know I can only sort within one facet. Any ideas how to do this?

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = coef, y = var)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  facet_wrap(~type,
             nrow = 1,
             scales = "free_x") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = .3) +
  theme_light()
```

```
d < - structure(list(var = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", 
"blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange"), coef = c(0.2, 
0.05, 0.23, 0.03, -0.15, -0.08, 0.32, -0.03, 0.1, -0.05), type = c("full", 
"full", "full", "full", "full", "half", "half", "half", "half", 
"half")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), coef = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000024d0c69a340>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like doing this with the `forcats` package. `fct_inorder` is a handy function where you just need to get the variables into the order you want (by their first appearance) and then they can become a factor in that order.

```
library(dplyr)
d |>
  arrange(type, coef) |>
  mutate(var = forcats::fct_inorder(var)) |>
ggplot(aes(x = coef, y = var)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  facet_wrap(~type,
             nrow = 1,
             scales = "free_x") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = .3) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

---

Here's the data I loaded, simplified:

```
d <- structure(list(var = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", 
"blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange"), coef = c(0.2, 
0.05, 0.23, 0.03, -0.15, -0.08, 0.32, -0.03, 0.1, -0.05), type = c("full", 
"full", "full", "full", "full", "half", "half", "half", "half", 
"half")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```